# Call Api with params

Tags: angular, laravel, http

I would like to make 10 calls to my api and have the result stored in a table.
At the moment my api call is successful but I don't know how to do this 10 times.
Each call sends different parameters to each call.

```
export class DataMlsService {

    ApiUrl = "publication/Mls";
    params = new HttpParams();
    statusParams = 'Archive';
    typeTransacParams = 'Vente';
    baux = this.params.set('status', this.statusParams).set('typeTransac', this.typeTransacParams);
        
    
    constructor(private apiClient: ApiClientService){}
    
    getRequest():Observable<any>{
        return this.apiClient.get(this.ApiUrl, { params: this.baux });
    }

}


export class MlsComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor (private dataMlsService: DataMlsService){}
  

  actifSinceOneDay(){
    //Colore la graphique en jaune lorsque le composant augmente.
  }
  listProducts: [];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.dataMlsService.getRequest()
    .subscribe(
      data=>{
          this.listProducts = data;
          console.log(data);
          console.log(this.listProducts.length);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better create a new function in your "API" that return the value, but you can use also forkJoin rxjs operator. You give few clues about your problem, But I suppose you has

```
//you has an array of params
params=[0,1,2,3,4,5]  
//you create an array of "calls" using map to transform the array
const calls:Observable<any>[]=this.params.map(x=>this.dataMlService.getData(x)
//you use forkJoin and subscribe
forkJoin(calls.susbcribe(res=>{
   //in res[0] you has the response to this.dataMlService.getData(0)
   //in res[1] you has the response to this.dataMlService.getData(1)
    ....
   console.log(res)

})
```